# Some questions about "can (not) help"

Tags: verbs, definition

It would be highly appreciated that one helps me to find an equivalent for sentences below:
In the OALD dictionary, it was written that: "sb **can (not)** help (doing) sth| sb cannot help but do sth"

1- I cannot help remembering it:
2- I can help remembering it:
3- I cannot help shutting my eyes:

Comment: What sort of 'equivalent' do you want? (1) I cannot forget it. (2) is not idiomatic English. (3) I cannot stop myself from shutting my eyes OR I cannot help but shut my eyes.

Comment: For the last one, can we say "I am fated to see it"?

Comment: @KateBunting Regarding equivalent, I meant what you wrote.

Comment: No, because if you can't help shutting your eyes, you can't see 'it'!

Comment: @KateBunting overabundant thanks. Accordingly, it means that "I am fated to close my eyes; thus, I cannot see it ".

Comment: Well, we usually close our eyes because of a physical compulsion (such as a dazzling light), or to avoid a horrible sight, rather than 'fate'!